# Is obtaining the closed form for a $k$-sheeted covering map of the bouquet of $n$ circles not possible?

Tags: algebraic-topology, reference-request, closed-form, covering-spaces

My question is:

> What's a closed form of a $k$-sheeted covering map $p:X\to S$, where $S=\Bbb S^1\vee\cdots\vee\Bbb S^1$, is the bouquet of $n$ circles.

I have always seen the interesting example of a triple-sheeted covering of $\Bbb S^1\vee\Bbb S^1$. But everywhere it was only sketched without any motivation or hints about how to write down an *actual* covering map that does exactly this. I have tried searching online as well as here on MSE but found nothing similar. So, I'm guessing it is just either impossible or too tedious to define a map that does this? Is this true? If yes, then why and do we even know that such a covering map even exists? Maybe I'm missing a reference that does the tedious steps? TIA.

Comment: What do you mean by "closed form"?

Comment: @Zest : By closed form I mean like a "formula". e.g. $\varepsilon(t)=e^{2\pi it}$ is a covering map for $\Bbb S^1$.

Comment: That's hard to do. Think of it this way: do you know of a way to embed the bouquet of $n$ circles into $\mathbb R^2$ so that you can parametrize the entire bouquet by a clean formula? Generally one understands the covering space theory of $\mathbb S^1$ quite explicitly, but for your situation one works circle-by-circle and then imposes compatibility conditions at the wedge points. Essentially you do everything piecewise.

Comment: @TabesBridges : do you then mean to say that it's too tedious that no one ever wrote it down or that it's just not possible? I understand that it's a messy piecewise defined map, but that wouldn't imply that such a map does exist, would it?

Comment: It's not impossible, just unspeakably tedious and without much point to it. A piecewise defined map is perfectly fine in terms of demonstrating existance.